# Why is passing a subclass to a bounded wildcard only allowed in certain places?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

This following is from generics tutorials:

Say class R extends S,

```
public void addR(List<? extends S> s) {
    s.add(0, new R()); // Compile-time error!
}
```

*You should be able to figure out why the code above is disallowed. The type of the second parameter to s.add() is ? extends S -- an unknown subtype of S. Since we don't know what type it is, we don't know if it is a supertype of R; it might or might not be such a supertype, so it isn't safe to pass a R there.*

I have read it a few times but still I don't quite understand why the following is an error

Given the List.add()'s signature

```
void add(int index, E element)
```

isn't it equivalent to

```
void add(int index, <? extends S> element) // just to explain the idea, not a valid syntax
```

why is it an error call add(0, new R()) R being an S?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what the text in italics is referring to:

The parameter `s`, of type `List<? extends S>`, could be not just an instance of `List<S>` or `List<R>`, but also `List<T>` where `T` extends `S`. In that case, even if `R` also extends `S`, `R` does not necessarily extend `T` (they could be, e.g. siblings in the class hierarchy). Since you can only put a value of type `T` in such a collection, the compiler can't guarantee at compile time that putting an `R` there would be safe.

To give a more concrete example, you can't add a `Double` to a `List<? extends Number>`, even though `Double` extends `Number`! That's because a variable of type `List<? extends Number>` *could*, for example, be assigned a `List<Integer>` at runtime, and adding a `Double` to such a list is not allowed.

In fact, you can't actually call the `add` method of a list declared to be `List<? extends S>`, because at runtime the wildcard could always represent some subtype of `S` that isn't a superclass of the thing you want to add. You can however *read* from such a list, since it's guaranteed that the wildcard is a subtype of `S`, and therefore can be assigned to a variable of type `S`:

```
public S getElement(List<? extends S> s) {
  S result = s.get(0);
  return result;
}
```

This general idea is referred to as PECS (producer-extends, consumer-super). Chapter 5 of [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) (conveniently enough, it's the sample chapter you can download from the book's website) has more to say about this and other subtleties of generics.

Comment: Wait T and R being siblings in class hierarchy and also being an S, why is it that you can only put a T in such a collection but not R?  Thanks for the link to Effective Java.

Comment: I added a more concrete example. Hopefully that helps a bit.

Comment: So what if it contains a List<Integer> and a List<Double>?  It is a heterogeneous List like the pre-JDK 1.4 List that is unparameterized. The get would still work fine since you are assigning to a Number type variable.

Comment: Good explanation by Phil!

The parameter type might be declared as List<? extends S>, but the actual value passed to the method at runtime will always be either a List<S>, List<R>, List<T> or List<SomethingElseExtendingTypeS>.

That's why the compiler is not convinced that adding a new R() to this List is a good idea,.

Comment: "you can't actually call the add method" you can always call it and pass `null`

Answer (score 0):

Figured this would be the simplest explanation

Class structure:

```
public class List<? extends S> {}
public class S {}
public class R extends S {}
public class T extends R {}
```

Code usage:

```
List<T> list = new List<T>();
```

in this case the following would be invalid:

```
list.add(new R());
```