# Demystify Wildcard for me

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Why do I get a compile time error on this piece of code?

```
public Interface Location {
 .......
}
```

Class code...

```
 Map<Type, List<? extends Location>> locationsTypeMap = new HashMap<Type, List<? extends Location>>();
  /**
   Code to add elements to the hashMap.
  */
  newLocation = getNewLocation()
  while(mapHasElements){
    Location.Type key = location.getType();
    List<? extends Location> valueList = (List<? extends Location>)locationsTypeMap.get(key); //1
    valueList.add(newLocation);/*Compile error*/
  }
```

On the other hand, if I replace step 1 with line below it works

```
List<Location> valueList = (List<Location>)locationsTypeMap.get(key);
```

Comment: SO members demystified this exact case earlier for me. Though you have accepted an answer you might still want to check this out: [Why is passing a subclass to a bounded wildcard only allowed in certain places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845276/why-is-passing-a-subclass-to-a-bounded-wildcard-only-allowed-in-certain-places)

Comment: The compiler should warn you about the cast being unsafe, (List<Location>) will compile to (List) which wont throw a class cast exception if your list is a List<SomeClass> and may cause class cast exceptions in other parts of your code if you insert objects

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The wildcard "? extends Location" means "I want it to be `List<T>` for some `T` where `T` is a subclass of `Location` (or is `Location` itself)."

Now, let's leave that to one side for a second. Would you expect *this* to compile:

```
List<String> strings = new List<String>();
strings.add(new Object());
```

? I wouldn't think so - you can't add a bare "object" to a list of strings. Any item in a list of strings has to be a string.

Go back to your first thing. Suppose `locationsTypeMap.get(key)` returns an object which is (logically - ignore type erasure for now) a `List<ExoticLocation>` - but suppose newLocation is actually an instance of `BoringLocation`. You shouldn't be able to add a `BoringLocation` to a `List<ExoticLocation>` and the compiler knows that - so it stops that from happening.

Anything you get *from* a `List<? extends Location>` is guaranteed to be a `Location` of some kind... but you can't add anything to it. The reverse is true with `super`: you can't guarantee that anything you get from a `List<? super Location>` will be a `Location`, but you *can* add a `Location` to it.

To give a very different example: is a bunch of bananas a collection of fruit? Well it is in one sense - anything you get from it *is* a fruit. But it's not in another, because you can't add any old kind of fruit to it - if you try to add an apple, it'll fall off :)

See [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for a lot more information.

Answer (score -1):

Its a nullable type like so:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28VS.80%29.aspx

EDIT: I must be wrong so, given the two answers above! Sorry!

Comment: Wrong language, and nothing to do with nullability. In C# this would be completely incorrect syntax.

Comment: I figured that after posting and edited, sorry new to stack overflow its my first time on a multi-language forum.