# Getting subclasses from Class<?>

Tags: java, reflection, reflections

I have a project where the service interfaces are annotated with a `@Service` annotation (custom annotation, not Spring) and there can be multiple implementation for each service (hibernate, mongodb, etc).

I am trying to load the implementation classes using reflection like this:

Step 1: Load all the interfaces with `@Service` annotation

Step 2: Load all sub classes for each of the interfaces

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("net.jitix.cfs");
    //load annotated interfaces
    Set<Class<?>> types=reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Service.class);

    Iterator<Class<?>> typeIterator=types.iterator();

    typeIterator.forEachRemaining(new Consumer<Class<?>>() {

        @Override
        public void accept(Class<?> type) {
            if(!type.isInterface()){
                typeIterator.remove();
            }
        }
    });

    for(Class<?> type:types){
        //load implementation classes
        Set<Class<?>> implTypes=reflections.getSubTypesOf(type); //error here
    }

    //rest of the code
}
```

The compile error I am getting: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<Class<? extends capture#8-of ?>> to Set<Class<?>>`

As per my [understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921676/what-does-class-mean-in-java) `Class<?>` signifies that the type can be anything, so I am confused why the method that requires `Class<T>` cannot take `Class<?>` as parameter.

Could anyone please help me understand why this is happening? Is there any possible alternatives to my approach? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: As per the comment by @MGorgon and answers by @StriplingWarrior and @Sotirios Delimanolis using the reflections method is out of question. Is there any way we can get the sub type of a type whose reference is of type `Class<?>`

Comment: What class is `ClassLoadingUtils`? What does `getUtility()` return? What is the method declaration of `getSubTypesOf`?

Comment: updated the code.. its just my utility method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292109/generics-get-and-put-rule

Comment: We can't see where the error is being generated, or the definitions of the methods you are calling.  There's no way to debug this without both of those things.  Complete details for both please.

Comment: @markspace I have added the full method. Its a compile time error

Comment: @JitB: I added a potential workaround in my answer. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crux of this question has nothing to do with reflection, but rather covariance/contravariance. It's effectively:

> Why can't I assign a `Set<? extends Something>` to a `Set<?>`?

And the answer is that if you had a `Set<?>` then the compiler would let you add an object of any type (say `X`) to that set, and someone trying to retrieve that value from the original `Set<? extends Something>` would get a runtime error when it turned out that your `X` *does not extend* `Something`.

The principle can be demonstrated even more simply like this:

```
Set<Dog> dogs = getDogs();
Set<Pet> pets = dogs;        // the compiler will complain here
pets.add(new Cat("Fluffy")); // to avoid letting this happen
for(Dog dog : dogs)         // which would cause an exception here
{
   ...
}
```

Since you (presumably) know that you're not planning to add anything to this set, however, it's probably safe to tell the compiler you know what you're doing through a little explicit casting:

```
Set<Class<?>> implTypes= (Set<Class<?>>)(Set<?>)reflections.getSubTypesOf(type);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getSubTypesOf` method is declared as

```
public <T> Set<Class<? extends T>> getSubTypesOf(final Class<T> type) {
```

It is a generic method, declaring `T` as a type parameter. When you invoke the method, the method invocation captures a type argument, either implicitly or because it was explicitly provided.

You've invoked the method with an argument of type `Class<?>`. The method will capture the `?` as type. The method return type will therefore become `Set<Class<? extends CAP of ?>>`, ie. a set of classes of some unknown type that is a subtype of some specific unknown type.

However, you are trying to assign that to a `Set<Class<?>>` which is a set of classes of some unknown type. But that unknown type is not necessarily a subtype of some specific unknown type. I know that doesn't make much sense when you say it out loud, but consider `?` or `CAP of ?` as a specific type. This is the same as trying to do

```
Set<Class<?>> implTypes = new HashSet<Class<Integer>>();
```

This isn't immediately obvious since `Class` is `final` and therefore cannot be subclassed, but a `HashSet<Class<Integer>>` is not assignable to `Set<Class<?>>` in the same way that a `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>` is not assignable to a `List<List<?>>`.

Additional reading:

- [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)