# In Java, how does the Object superclass have a getClass() method with return type as the specific Class?

Tags: java, object

An example - When an instance `abc` of `Foo` is created, and when `abc.getClass()` is invoked, it returns an instance of type `Class<Foo>` - But how did the `Object` superclass know the return (specific) `Class` type beforehand?

If `Dog` extends `Animal` superclass, `Dog` can invoke only `Animal` methods that were defined when `Animal` was created / compiled. Based on same principle, `Object` being the superclass of all Classes, how does it dynamically know the return `Class` type on `getClass()` method? - Am I missing/assuming incorrect on the fundamentals?

for the foo instance, the Object superclass would have the method declaration like this - public final native Class"<"Foo">" getClass(); how did the object know this method i.e. Class"<"Foo">" getClass () without we even doing anything? Or is the return type generic Class rather than a specific Class?

Comment: The magic of polymorphism at work.

Comment: `getClass()` is a native method. If you decompile rt.jar you will find out how the method `getClass()` is declared in `Object`: `public final native Class<?> getClass();`

Comment: Thanks - but for the foo instance, the Object superclass would have the method declaration like this - public final native Class<Foo> getClass(); My question was how did the object know this method i.e. Class<Foo> getClass () without we even doing anything? Or is the return type generic Class rather than a specific Class?

Comment: The return type is Class<?>

Comment: Thanks - Is it with the questionmark the return type is defined in Object class? I thought the actual classname was substituted in the Object class e.g.:- Class"<"Foo">"

Comment: Got the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9921745/4740198