# What does this Java syntax mean? (` Class<? extends E> clazz`)

Tags: java

I need a custom method to check for a list containing an instance of a class and call this method but I do not understand this syntax "Class clazz" and  I do not understand What's the second parameter of this method

```
public static <E> boolean containsInstanceOfOidInrArraylist(List<E> Arraylist, Class<? extends E> clazz) {
        for (E e : Arraylist) {
            if (clazz.isInstance(e)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I recommend you to start by learning about `Generics`.

Comment: The [Java Tutorial on Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) is probably a good place to start

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java). This has a nice explanation.

Comment: After reading the tutorial as recommended by DB, `Class` is the name of a class (it is `java.lang.Class`), and `clazz` is a variable name ... chosen because you can'e use `class` as a variable name.

Comment: Further, the combination of ```List<E>``` and ```Class<? extends E>``` is telling you something about argument compatibility.  Given```List<Number>``` (say) then```Class<String>``` is not acceptable; but "Class<Number>" and  "Class<Integer>" are.

Comment: And finally, you can get a value for the second argument by an expression such as ```Integer.class``  -- i.e., every class has an associated Class instance/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the first parameter of the function is a `List<E>` named `Arraylist` (You shouldn't capitalize variables in Java, name it as such `arrayList`).

The second parameter is a `Class<? extends E>` named `clazz`.

Check [manub's explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9921745/8516624) of `Class<?>`:

> `Class` is a parameterizable class, hence you can use the syntax
>   `Class<T>` where `T` is a type. By writing `Class<?>`, you're declaring a
>   `Class` object which can be of any type (`?` is a wildcard). The `Class`
>   type is a type that contains meta-information about a class.

So now you know what `Class<?>` means, but what about `Class<? extends E>`?

`<? extends E>` basically means **any class which extends E (or E itself).**

So `Class<? extends E> clazz` means you have a varaible named `clazz` which is `E` class or a sub class of `E`.

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html

"Upper Bounded Wildcards
You can use an upper bounded wildcard to relax the restrictions on a variable. For example, say you want to write a method that works on `List<Integer>`, `List<Double>`, and `List<Number>`; you can achieve this by using an upper bounded wildcard.

To declare an upper-bounded wildcard, use the wildcard character ('?'), followed by the extends keyword, followed by its upper bound. Note that, in this context, extends is used in a general sense to mean either "extends" (as in classes) or "implements" (as in interfaces)."

The second parameter is a class that is the same as the class of the objects in the list, or extends it. clazz is used as a variable name because class is a reserved keyword and cannot be used.

Comment: Hi, please provide us your code and question. Now we don't know what is your problem with linked tutorial.