# Type mismatch Error : Cannont convert from ArrayList<SubClass1> to List<SuperClass>

Tags: java, list, arraylist, type-mismatch

Here is my class Structure, and where I am getting error

```
class SuperClass{
//variables
}

class SubClass1 extends SuperClass{
//variables
}

class SubClass2 extends SuperClass{
//variables
}

class AClass{
List<SuperClass> list;

public AClass(boolean b){
if(b)
list = new ArrayList<SubClass1>();//getting error here
else
list = new ArrayList<SubClass2>();//and here
}
void addObjects(SuperClass obj){
list.add(obj);
}

}
```

How can I solve this? Should I change my design ? How?

**ADDITION:**

When I changed

```
`List<SuperClass> list;`
```

to
    `List<? extends SuperClass> list;`

I am not getting the previous error but I am getting another error while adding objects,

`The method add(capture#2-of ? extends SuperClass) in the type List<capture#2-of ? extends SuperClass> is not applicable for the arguments (SuperClass)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're trying to create a list that only contains objects from the particular subclass. In this case you just need the generics to play nice at compile time. (Generics are erased at runtime :) )

```
class AClass<T extends SuperClass> {
    List<T> list;

    public AClass(){
        list = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    void addObjects(T obj){
        list.add(obj);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use a bounded wildcard in your ArrayList declaration:

```
 class AClass{

      List<? extends SuperClass> list;

      public AClass(boolean b){
         if(b)
          list = new ArrayList<SubClass1>();
        else
          list = new ArrayList<SubClass2>();
        }
      }
}
```

The `?` is a wildcard and defines an unknown type. But by using a bounded wildcard you can assure that it is an unknown subtype of SuperClass.

For further information about wildcards see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Concerning you're other problem:

The type of the parameter to list.add() is ? extends

> SuperClass-- an unknown subtype of SuperClass.
>   Since we don't know what type it is,
>   we don't know if it is a supertype. it might or might not be
>   such a supertype, so it isn't safe to
>   pass a SubClass1 or SubClass2 there.

Comment: @Roflcoptr,
Now I am not getting the compile error at,  

    list = new ArrayList<SubClass1>();  

but when I try to add objects,
    list.add(subClass1Object);

I am getting following error,   
The method add(capture#2-of ? extends SuperClass) in the type List<capture#2-of ? extends SuperClass> is not applicable for the arguments (SubClass1)

Comment: @Roflcoptr, I read the link you gave, it also discusses the problem I am getting, but it doesn't give any solution to that, it says,

"
You should be able to figure out why the code above is disallowed. The type of the second parameter to shapes.add() is ? extends Shape-- an unknown subtype of Shape. Since we don't know what type it is, we don't know if it is a supertype of Rectangle; it might or might not be such a supertype, so it isn't safe to pass a Rectangle there.
"

Comment: Yes. So the short answer is. You can't call the add method, because on runtime, it always could always be a subclass of the wildcard but not a supertype of the object you want to add.

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845276/why-is-passing-a-subclass-to-a-bounded-wildcard-only-allowed-in-certain-places/1845319#1845319

Comment: Thanks for the link. So, could you think of any other way?