# Error Type mismatch: cannot convert

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Help me please. I am a student. 
I have abstract `class A`. `Class A1 extends A`.
If I write

```
ArrayList<A> a = ArrayList<A1> a1
```

I get error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<A1> to ArrayList<A>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type mismatch Error : Cannont convert from ArrayList<SubClass1> to List<SuperClass>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533368/type-mismatch-error-cannont-convert-from-arraylistsubclass1-to-listsupercla)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot Cast from `ArrayList<A1>` to other type `ArrayList<A>` using [**`TypeErasure`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html),So I suggest you to try with using [**`WildCard`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) in java for this case

```
ArrayList<? extends A1>a1=new ArrayList<A1>();
     ArrayList<? extends A1> a =  a1;
```

Answer (score -1):

In the following `a` list declaration,

```
ArrayList<A> a
```

the type rules say that `a` list can only contain object of exactly `A` type: it cannot, for instance, contain any other type of type object which extends super type `A`.

To solve this problem you can use [Bounded Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)  as follows...

```
ArrayList<? extends A> a = a1
```

Now `a` list will accept lists of any subclass of `A`. Here, The ? stands for an unknown type, but this unknown type is in fact a subtype of Shape. (Note: It could be `A` itself, or some subclass; it need not literally extend `A`).

Comment: write "Cannot cast from ArrayList<A1> to ArrayList<A>"

Comment: The compiler will not allow this cast. And I appreciate it. If it was allowed, you could now have a `class A2 extends A` and write `a.add(new A2())`. But in fact it was a list that only should have allowed instances of A1!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose...I appreciate your concern. Now, I have update my answer. Let me know if you have any more concern.