# Reason of Type mismatch Error : convert ArrayList<SubClass1> to List<SuperClass>?

Tags: java, arraylist, type-conversion, type-mismatch

Class B extends class A.We can use this statement:

```
A a = new B();
```

But why we can not use this code:

```
List<A> listOfA = new ArrayList<B>();
```

Of course,we can use [generics to avoid that error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5533541/1043882).But my question is in about reason of rising that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the reason would be because the java developer doesn't want to repeat their mistake they did in array. For example,

```
 Object x[] = new String[3];
 x[0] = new Integer(0);
```

this code gives a runtime exception [`java.lang.ArrayStoreException`](http://ideone.com/OGYvf6)

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
List<? extends A> listOfA = new ArrayList<B>();
```

Comment: ,yes of course!We can use generics to avoid error.But my question is in about `why that error occurs?`

Answer (score 0):

If you can do this, you can then write

```
listOfA.add(new A());
```

which inserts an object of type `A` into `ArrayList<B>`.

Answer (score 0):

here the rule is quite simple.`List` is super type(or interface) of `ArrayList`.So you can safely assign a `ArrayList` reference to a `List` variable.But this is for non-generic type.`List` & `ArrayList` are like templates,if you create it in generic way type of the variable declaration must match the type you pass to the actual object type.It is the generic type safety,so that you know(from compiler perspective) that you can do type safe operation for every object inside that list.

Comment: So if you define something like this List<MyObjType> list,you must assign any concrete implementation of List having MyObjType